# Custom contrasts with emmeans

Tags: r, emmeans

I would like to compute specific contrasts (i.e. 1_1 vs. 3_3 and 1_3 vs. 3_1) of my factor levels but not sure if this is the correct procedure.

When I run the plot() function it gives me, I guess, a plot that looks like a pairs() function computation (same for eff_size(contr) not shown here). Whereas if I plot my 'post' object it gives me the desired plot but wrong p-values compared to 'contr' object p-values (below).

Many thanks

```
post <- emmeans(fit, specs = contr ~ Condition ,pbkrtest.limit = 4959)

 Condition emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 1_1         6.77 0.0304 85.2     6.71     6.83
 3_3         6.81 0.0304 85.1     6.75     6.87
 1_3         6.88 0.0305 86.0     6.82     6.94
 3_1         6.88 0.0305 85.8     6.82     6.95

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

levels(df$Condition)
[1] "1_1" "3_3" "1_3" "3_1"

c1_1 <- c(1,0,0,0)
c3_3 <- c(0,1,0,0)
c1_3 <- c(0,0,1,0)
c3_1 <- c(0,0,0,1)

contr <- contrast(post, method = list("1_1 - 3_3" = c1_1 - c3_3,
                                      "3_3 - 3_1" = c3_3 - c3_1), adjust = "bonferroni")
contr
 contrast  estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1_1 - 3_3  -0.0408 0.0164 74.4 -2.490  0.0300 
 3_3 - 3_1  -0.0776 0.0165 76.2 -4.708  <.0001 

plot(contr, comparisons = T)

pairs(contr)
 contrast              estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1_1 - 3_3 - 3_3 - 3_1   0.0368 0.0284 75.1 1.294   0.1996 

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

Comment: Looks good to me, and the estimates conform with the means.

Comment: Many thanks! But how to deal with the plot () function? When I plot the "contr" object the output is a plot that compares 1_1 - 3_3 vs. 3_3-3_1 as in pair(), whereas when I plot "post" object it gives me the correct comparisons but wrong p-values (i.e 1_1 vs 3_3 according to red arrows are not significant, whereas in "contr" object they are).

Comment: Well, that isn't surprising at all if you used the default p-value adjustments. For `post`, you have comparisons among 4 means, 6 pairwise comparisons altogether, with a Tukey adjustment by default; whereas with `contr`, you have just two of those six comparisons. `pairs(contr)` gives you a comparison of 1_1 and 3_1, and there is just one comparison in thatfamily so no multiplicity adjustment.